# Dependecy wdio-cucumber-framework is not getting installed when I use node version 12. Its installing till node 10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cucumber, wdio-v5

Dependecy **wdio-cucumber-framework** is not getting installed when I use node version 12. Its installing till node 10

Throwing error "Failed at the fibers@2.0.2 install script"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it.

here is my dependencies:

```
 "@wdio/cli": "^6.1.5",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^6.1.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.1.5",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.1.5",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.1.5",
    "chromedriver": "^81.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.2"
```

and node version: `v12.16.3`